# SQLite- elegantly setting IDs

Tags: sql, sqlite

I want to use a database like:

> table wrongdoer (primarykey integer
>   ID, date)
>
> table crime (numeric
>   foreign_key_to_wrongdoer, text crime)

I want my application (in python) to register a wrongdoer (which should give the entry a unique integer) and register the first crime against him. My idea is rather clumsy:

> insert into wrongdoer(...)
>
> id=cur.execute("select max(ID)")
>      //this is to select the most recent ID
>
> cur.execute("insert into
>   crime('"+id+"'"crime+"'")")

That is, insert an entry, select its unique key from DB (assuming its the highest number), and then use it for the subsequent queries. Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this function out:
http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/last_insert_rowid.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What if there are multiple threads INSERTing into the database? How do you ensure that we get the rowid even if another thread is likely to insert a row before our get rowid command?

Comment: When you do insert use BEGIN EXCLUSIVE TRANSACTION statement. See here: http://www.sqlite.org/lang_transaction.html